# Getting Run Time Error - Running Pivot using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Run-Time error '1004';

Method 'PivotTables' of object'_Worksheet'Failed while running below code to create pivot table.

I am trying to add pivote table using VBA but not able to run the macro.

```
    Sub PivotTable()

  Dim pvtable As PivotTable
  Dim pvcache As PivotCache
  Dim pvrange As Range
  Dim pvsheet As Worksheet
  Dim pdsheet As Worksheet
  
  Dim plr As Long
  Dim plc As Long

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Worksheets("Dealer List").Delete 'to delete the exisiting pivot table in the worksheet
'Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet ' to add a new worksheet
'
'ActiveSheet.Name = "Dealer List" ' to rename the worksheet into "pvsheet"

On Error GoTo 0

Set pvsheet = Worksheets("Dealer List")
Set pdsheet = Worksheets("Citi Fail Report")

'two variable to find Last used row and column in pdsheet
plr = pdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
plc = pdsheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'initializing pivot table data range

Set pvrange = pdsheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(plr, plc)

'pivot cahe
Set pvcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=pvrange)


'new blank pivot table
Set pvtable = pvcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pvsheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Sales_Report")

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Insert Product to Row Filed
With pvsheet.PivotTables("Sales_Report").PivotFields("Trader Name")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
  .Position = 1
End With

'Insert town to Column Filed
With pvsheet.PivotTables("Sales_Report").PivotFields("Fund")
  .Orientation = xlColumnField
  .Position = 1
End With

'set the format Pivot Table
pvsheet.PivotTables("Sales_Report").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
pvsheet.PivotTables("Sales_Report").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium14"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Could you please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: The code runs okay for me; what line is it failing on when you run it?

Comment: Once you have that reference to `pvtable` you should use that in place of `pvsheet.PivotTables("Sales_Report")`